# T-SQL - synchronize query result with table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have sql query composed from 3 tables. I need to synchronize the query result with 1 table every 24 hours.

The idea is to run query every 24 hours. Compare the result with target table. Delete the target table rows, insert new ones or update existing rows.

I'm asking for "best-practices" to deal with this kind of situation.
Thank you.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using?

Comment: Have you looked at the `MERGE` statement? This can exactly achieve the things you describe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx
Use your SQL query as SOURCE and the table where you want to synchronize to as TARGET.

Comment: @NickyvV: Thank you for your suggestion. I looked at the MERGE statement. Seems like the best solution. Btw I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition.